# VB.NET forms keep disappearing while system is in use

Tags: vb.net, winforms

We have a "Core" system that we use to run the business and there are about 15-18 people using it at any one time. The program is written in VB.NET and has about 165 forms.

The way it works is when the user runs the program he/she is prompted to log in and if the login is successful a "Main" form is displayed with a number of menus (Customers, Suppliers...). From there they can click on the menus which open another form on top of the "Main" (the "Main" form needs to be visible in the background because it displays information that is relevant to the users while they are in other screens)

The issue we are having is that if the users have other programs open while using the "Core" system (Outlook, Word, Chrome, anything really) and switch to another program and then back to the system, it only displays the "Main" form and any other forms open on top disappear. The way we get around this is by switching back to the other programs they have open and clicking on the minimise button in the top right corner of the window until all the other programs are minimised, which only leaves the "Core" system visible. However this is becoming a nuisance to all the users (including myself and the other developer) and we really need to sort this issue out in order to keep out staff happy :)

I would appreciate any advice or pointers in the right direction which will help us solve this issue and please feel free to ask if you need any more information.

Comment: Can you make this question a little more specific please - how are the forms being displayed, are they popups, MDI?

Comment: @TonyDay sorry for omitting this information. The way we display any form is by using Me.ShowDialog()

Comment: Perhaps you need to pass in the parent form (Main) to the dialogue? Me.ShowDialog(parent)?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. For example, a user logs into the system and the "Main" form is displayed. If the user clicks on the "Customer" button the following code is ran (some bits have been taken out):
 `

        CloseOpenForms()
        Find_Customer.Setup("Main")

The Find_Customer.Setup form executes the following code:

        SetupGrid()

        PopulateGrid()

        ...


        Me.ShowDialog() 'this shows the Find_Customer form `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are creating the `ChildForm` from the `MainForm` but the `ChildForm` itself is showing itself with `Me.ShowDialog()`.  What you should probably try is showing the form from the `MainForm` and passing the `MainForm` in as the parent. This should keep the form tied to it's parent and on top.  For example:

```
childForm.showDialog(Me)
```

Where `Me` is the `MainForm`. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w61zzfwe.aspx) is the documentation for that method.

This is the important part:

> Owner Type: System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window
>
> Any object that implements IWin32Window that represents the top-level window that will own the modal dialog box.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It does make sense however the "Me.ShowDialog()" is used in the "Find_Customer.Setup()" form and not in the "Main" form. Also, we have to show the dialog for each form from within each form rather than from the "Main" Hope you understand what I mean

Comment: @OopsieDaisie I understand what you mean now. However, can you call  `Find_Customer.ShowDialog(Me)` (or something like it) in `MainForm` instead of in `Setup`. This is so that Main is showing the form and not the form showing itself.

Comment: that would mean changing a hell of a lot of code and testing of the full system would have to be performed to ensure it works as expected. However, if that is our only choice then I guess we can call  the forms from the "Main" form. At the end of the day that is our job - to write code and keep customers happy :)

Comment: @OopsieDaisie Another approach could be to pass the MainForm into the setup method and then pass it into the `Me.ShowDialog(mainForm)` method. I believe the dialog needs to know about it's parent like this to solve your problem.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. The "Main" form is displayed when the user logs in and always stays open unless the user closes the whole application (i.e. end of day). How could I adapt it to meet my needs?

Comment: It's not the main for that needs to change. You need to pass the main form instance into the Customer form's `Setup` method: `Find_Customer.Setup("Main", Me)`.  Can you post some of your code in your question please?

Comment: I now understand what you mean. I used `Me.ShowDialog(Main)` from within the Customer screen and that gets rid of the issue we are having. I assume if we have a link to another screen from the Customer screen, we need to set the parent of that screen to be the "Customer" screen correct?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right - it's a parent/child relationship so that windows are correctly organised. Glad it helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

Changing code to show dialog will change behavior of your code little bit, like your main from execution will hold till you close child form

But you can you use only show as child (not dialog)

```
childForm.show (Me)
```

This will not change anything except whenever you click on main form it will display its entire children on it.